# How to re enable submit button in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

i have this simple button

```
<button [disabled]="!f.form.valid " type="submit">
                            Submit
                         </button>
```

on form submit it disables again to avoid multiple submit but if any server error occures (validation etc) it stays disabled , how do i enable it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component(...)    
export class Example{
...
private requestSent: boolean;
...


public sendRequest() {
   this.requestSent = true;
   this.someService.sendReq().then( response => {
    this.requestSent = false;
  })
}

}

<button [disabled]="requestSent">
                        Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind it to any boolean property in your component, like "requestSent" or "succeeded", but not to the form validness.
In promise callback you will handle them, so you will prevent any double submitting

Comment: is there any example of it  In promise callback ??